# Assign and read from an array entry in PHP in one statement

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to make some sort of elegant way to do an all-in-one while loop clause, but I'm not sure if it's possible.

To start, I have a 2-D array which was generated from a CSV. Something like this:

```
1  2  3  4
1  2  3  4
2  5  2  3
A  1  1  1
```

Let's call this `$arr`.

I want to iterate through the array starting at some `$index`, and stop when I find the first row where the 0th element is not a number. So say we started at `$arr[1]`, it would run the loop for `$arr[1]` and `$arr[2]`, but would stop at `$arr[3]`, since `$arr[3][0]` is not a number.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
while ( is_numeric( ($row = $arr[++$index])[0] ) )
```

It doesn't like me trying to access the 0th element of that assignment inside the parentheses:

```
($row = $arr[++$index])[0] //Unexpected '['
```

I'm guessing that what's inside the parentheses is not returning what I would expect, or maybe PHP just doesn't support this kind of syntax. Is there a way to assign an array element to another variable and read from it in the same statement like this?

Comment: Why not just `while (($row = $arr[++$index]) && is_numeric($row[0]))`?

Comment: This works fine in PHP 7, only the old, massively outdated versions of the 5 branch throw this error - https://3v4l.org/U9gJP. If you are still using any of those, why don’t you just go shoot yourself in the foot directly, saves time :-)

Comment: There's not really a *good* reason why not. I've just done something similar to this in other languages and was surprised when it threw an error in PHP. I wanted to see if there was a way to do it with just one clause.

Comment: @04FS Really? It's just because of the PHP version? Well unfortunately I can't control what version of PHP our server at work uses.

Comment: If you have any servers in production use that still use PHP 5, it is time to either upgrade them, or shut them down immediately - the 5 branch does not even get security fixes any more. And if that is not an option, due to {insert pretend bogus reasons here} – well then you have to write code that is a little less “fancy”, simple as that.

Comment: Good to know. I'll see what I can do. Thanks for the help.

Comment: And in the end - `$arr[++$index]` with `$index` out of bounds will bring you a `Warning`.

Comment: What do you need to do what the search is satisfied? I'm not sure that I'd even bother to convert to an array. How big is the csv?  What does some of that data look like?

Comment: @mickmackusa It could theoretically be up to about 5000 rows and 25 columns. Maybe about 5 MB of data.

Comment: How about my other requests for clarification?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what technique you use to identify the non-numeric first column value, just hang on to the incrementing variable.

Here is one way:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/gDKqN))

```
$array = [
    [1,  2,  3,  4],
    [1,  2,  3,  4],
    [2,  5,  2,  3],
    ['A',1,  1,  1],
    [3,  6,  6,  6]
];
$i = -1;

while (!ctype_alpha((string)$array[++$i][0]));

echo "Halted on row index: $i\n";
var_export($array[$i]);
```

Output:

```
Halted on row index: 3
array (
  0 => 'A',
  1 => 1,
  2 => 1,
  3 => 1,
)
```